# Centreline extraction in matlab

Tags: matlab

Im trying to perform centerline extraction for cardiac CT images, and I am stuck. I need an example code that uses the "fast marching method". I got this code from mathworks.

```
I1=im2double(imread('se036.png'));
SpeedImage=I1*1000+0.001;
SourcePoint=[800;803];
DistanceMap= msfm(SpeedImage, SourcePoint);
figure
imshow(DistanceMap,[0 3400]) StartPoint=[9;14];
ShortestLine=shortestpath(DistanceMap,StartPoint,SourcePoint);
hold on
plot(ShortestLine(:,2),ShortestLine(:,1),'r')
```

But I get error message `Undefined function 'msfm' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For a question on Stack Overflow it is expected that you provide a clear description of what you want to achieve, describe your own attempts to answer the question, and state exactly where you got stuck. Moreover, most of the time it increases the chances for a good answer if you include some context and motivation and a *small* piece of (non-) working code (possibly including data).

Comment: @Donda: Ill keep that in mind. I got this code from mathworks.I1=im2double(imread('se036.png'));
SpeedImage=I1*1000+0.001;
SourcePoint=[800;803];
DistanceMap= msfm(SpeedImage, SourcePoint); 
figure, imshow(DistanceMap,[0 3400])
StartPoint=[9;14];
ShortestLine=shortestpath(DistanceMap,StartPoint,SourcePoint);
hold on, plot(ShortestLine(:,2),ShortestLine(:,1),'r')        But I get error message....         Undefined function 'msfm' for input arguments of type 'double'.Pls help....

Comment: There are some things it is good to learn to get something out of SO. One of them is: If you want to provide more info, do so by *editing* you question. I now did so for you. – Most important things to look at: the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [formatting info](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to use the Matlab File Exchange submission [Accurate Fast Marching](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24531-accurate-fast-marching/content/msfm.m) but you haven't properly installed the code. The function file you downloaded, `msfm.m`, needs to be in a folder on your path or in the current working directory.